# android:backgroundTint isn't working - Android

Tags: android, xml

Can someone please help me figure out why is the backgroundTint for the button not working? I use `android:background` for the background color and `android:backgroundTint` for the button background. But it seems like the BackgroundTint is not working (the button background color is set to default).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCounter"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/default_background"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="200sp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvCounter">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:onClick="gantiBackground"
                android:text="HITAM"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
                android:background="@color/red"
                android:onClick="gantiBackground"
                android:text="MERAH"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
                android:background="@color/blue"
                android:onClick="gantiBackground"
                android:text="BIRU"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/green"
                android:background="@color/green"
                android:onClick="gantiBackground"
                android:text="HIJAU"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button10"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="tambahCounter"
                android:text="TAMBAH"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="reset"
                android:text="RESET"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use app:backgroundTint instead of android:backgroundTint

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/black"//edited line
            android:background="@color/black"
            android:onClick="gantiBackground"
            android:text="HITAM"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/red"//edited line
            android:background="@color/red"
            android:onClick="gantiBackground"
            android:text="MERAH"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/blue"//edited line
            android:background="@color/blue"
            android:onClick="gantiBackground"
            android:text="BIRU"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/green"//edited line
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:onClick="gantiBackground"
            android:text="HIJAU"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
android:background="@color/red"
```

InsteadOf

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/blue"
android:background="@color/blue"
```

Try Different Color For "background" And "backgroundTint"

You Use Same Color for "background" And "backgroundTint"..That's Why "backgroundTint" look like does not work...

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: Which Theme You are using for that Activity...?

Comment: Set @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar theme..

Answer (score 0):

Not working in lower Android SDK(E.g. Jellybean).

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlue"
```

Use

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlue"
```

Will work for all Android SDKs.